# Union of two context-free grammars and their productions

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, formal-grammars

Is it possible to create an union of two context-free grammars? I found a PDF material from the university of Iowa where they claim that it's possible but I just don't know how. They had that for grammar G1:

$S_1 \rightarrow 0S_11 | \epsilon$

and for grammar G2

$S_2 \rightarrow 1S_20$

Now they created a union by doing:

$S \rightarrow S_1|S_2$

$S_1 \rightarrow 0S_11 | \epsilon$

$S_2 \rightarrow 1S_20$

But my situation is like this:

**Grammar** $G_1$:

$S_1 \rightarrow aS_2 | a$

$S_2 \rightarrow aS_2b | \epsilon$

**Grammar** $G_2$:

$S_3 \rightarrow aaS_4 | a$

$S_4 \rightarrow aS_4b | \epsilon$

How do I proceed from here, since I don't simply have one production rule per grammar?

Comment: You can solve this question by generalizing the examples you have been given.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That's what I am having trouble with - generalizing it. I've found no general formula for this. What am I supposed to do? Just introduce a new rule 

$S \rightarrow S_1 | S_2 | S_3 | S_4$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of *initial symbol* or *start symbol*?