# context free grammar for ${\{0^i1^j0^k1^l0^m \mid i, j, k, l, m \ge 0, i \le k\text{ or }j = m\text{ (or both)}\}}$

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I'm trying to come up with a context free grammar for the following language: $${\{0^i1^j0^k1^l0^m | i, j, k, l, m \ge 0, i \le k \text{ or } j = m \text{ (or both)}\}}$$
I'm able to come up with rules for the $i ≤ k$ case and I think the $j = m$ case but the both case is killing me.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to do anything for the "both" case? Context-free grammars don't have to be unambiguous.

Comment: I know It doesnt have to be unambiguous, but the way ive thought about it, I wrote rules for the first two cases individually, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around satisfying both cases

Comment: If you have both cases, you've got it cased. Suppose you have some language $L_1$ with starting production $S_1$ and some language $L_2$ with starting production $S_2$. What then is the language $L$ with starting production $S$ and rules $S\to S_1; S\to S_2$ plus all the rules for $L_1$ and $L_2$ (ensuring that the non-terminals have different names)? (And how else would you write the union of two languages?)

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133831/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Closure, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Closure_properties, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151912/755

Comment: Note that this "or both" thing is basically a construct of English (and maybe other human languages) but is not necessary in mathematics. $a\lor b$ is true when $a$ is true and also when $b$ is true. $P\cup Q$ contains all the elements of $P$ as well as all the elements of $Q$; you don't have to say that.